# FormGroup in Div highlights all Fields when validation fails

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, formbuilder, formgroups

I need to reuse 2 fields - produced date and expiry date in my angular application.

Note: I must use <div [formGroup]...> because this component will be called in other forms. I cannot use the form tag here.

I have created the below component - MyFilter.component.ts:

```
export class MyFilterComponent {
  filterForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.filterForm = formBuilder.group({
      producedDate: ['', [Validators.required]],
      expiryDate: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
}
```

Then I have the below my-filter.component.html:

```
<div [formGroup]="filterForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="producedDate"> Produced Date</label>
        <input type="date" formControlName="producedDate" class="form-control">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" name="producedDateRequiredWarning"
            *ngIf="filterForm.get('producedDate').errors && filterForm.get('producedDate').touched">
            Field is Required.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="expiryDate"> Expiry Date</label>
        <input type="date" formControlName="expiryDate" class="form-control">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" name="expiryDateRequiredWarning"
            *ngIf="filterForm.get('expiryDate').errors && filterForm.get('expiryDate').touched">
            Field is Required.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a validation fails - i.e. If I touch the produceddate field and do not enter anything, I expect only that field to be highlighted in red. But I am currently getting a long border on the left as below:

Is there a way to get rid of this without overriding the css?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ngIf condition to this:

```
*ngIf="filterForm.get('producedDate').touched && filterForm.get('producedDate').hasError('required')"
```